# Replace a JPanel with the same with updated contents

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Here I have a `JPanel` with `JLabels` and `JTextfields` and some `JButtons`.  Where one `JTextfield` is to get data from user and on clicking search button, it should get the relevant data from the database and display the result in the same panel. When I click submit button. I find no change in my screen, but when I resize the frame I can see the updated panel behind the previous one.  Even I try `remove(rp)` and then add it results the same as above.

How to replace a JPanel with the same with updated contents?

P.S: I want to remove and add the same panel with updated contents

my code looks like this while replacing

```
private void rp_validate(){
     f.add(rp);
     f.revalidate();
     f.repaint();
     f.pack();
}
```

Comment: `"I want to remove and add the same panel with updated contents"` -- then do this. If you need help doing this, show us your code attempt. You're asking us to help you figure out what's wrong with your code without showing us any code. Please tell us, how on earth are we supposed to do this? You will want to create an post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Also why not leave the JPanel in place and simply change the contents displayed in its fields?

Comment: Just a guess (since you didn't provide SSCCE): Call repaint() and revalidate() for panel...I can bet that should do a thing.

Comment: No, the need is to update a panel not exchange two panels. Post your code and we'll help you to improve it. But try at least writing yourself the first version

Comment: my code would look like this while replacing !!          
    }
    private void rp_validate(){
         
                       
               
                
                f.add(rp);
                f.revalidate();
                f.repaint();
                f.pack();
    }
     private void searchbutton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        
         // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    search(searchtf.getText().trim());
  
    
     }

Comment: @brano88 *"Call repaint() and revalidate() for panel...I can bet that should do a thing."*  Every time I hear the `repaint()/revalidate()` combo. I think **`CardLayout`**!  ;)

Comment: unfortunately i am done with all designing .. i don wanna switch over layouts now.. maybe i ll try that next time .. my code will look like 
          
    }
    private void rp_validate(){
         
                       
               
                
                f.add(rp);
                f.revalidate();
                f.repaint();
                f.pack();
    }

Comment: If you don't want the answer, don't ask the question.

Comment: i have updated in the question

Comment: You should not swap JPanels. If you're displaying new information in the same JPanel, then simply set the JTextFields and JLabels appropriately. You could create a method that automates this for you. No need to use CardLayout, no need to revalidate or repaint. Just call `setText(...)` a few times.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels assume that i have a panel with all labels and textfields set.. also i have searchbox on same panel and i click on it.. it should display different results in same labels and textfields

Comment: @GowthamRavichandran: I assume nothing. The class that holds that JPanel could easily be given a public method, say `public setDisplayedData(MyData myData)` that accepts an object of some class that holds all the data, and then uses it to update the fields.

Comment: @brano88 i have done the same ... jus check the code above.. but still the problem persists

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: i can get sth out of your comment but .. not clearly can u give some example... and moreover i have to get the data from a database

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class that holds all the necessary data obtained from your Database query.
2. Give the GUI class that holds your JPanel a public "setter" method that accepts an instance of the above class.
3. Then inside of the JPanel class, call `setText(...)` passing information held in the setter method parameter to update the text displayed in your JPanel. Simple as pie.

Fore example:

```
public void setMyData(MyData myData) {
   this.myData = myData;
   lastNameTextField.setText(myData.getLastName());
   firstNameTextField.setText(myData.getFirstName());
   addressTextfield.setText(myData.getAddress());
   cityTextfield.setText(myData.getCity());
   stateTextfield.setText(myData.getState());
   // ... etc
}
```

Comment: how the MyData class will look like

Comment: @Gowtham Ravichandran 1. reuse JComponets that exists, 2. JComponent and its variables wouldn't be static

Comment: @GowthamRavichandran: the MyData class will all depend on what information is pulled out of the database and displayed. There will likely be fields to match the JTextFields that display the information.